# Text imbrication and style in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to change style in part of Text in React Native.

I tried this :

```
<Text style={styles.parent}>
    Dernier message : <Text style={[styles.children, {
        color: 'red',
        paddingLeft: 10,
        borderWidth: 5,
        borderColor: 'black',
    }]}>Coucou</Text>
</Text>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    parent: {
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    },
    children: {
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
    },
})
```

- Parent background color is changed - good
- Children color and background color is changed - good
- **Children padding left and border is not changed**

Can you help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<Text>` element is special as far as layout is concerned. From the docs: "everything inside is no longer using the flexbox layout but using text layout. This means that elements inside of a `<Text>` are no longer rectangles, but wrap when they see the end of the line."

To achieve what you seem to be looking for, it's probably advisable to use a wrapping`<View>` with two inner `<Text>s`.

PFB the expo snack link. Hope it helps
[Expo link](https://snack.expo.io/HktrGEVYH)

Comment: and you can now customize according to your requirements by adding styles